# Netsuite suitelet cant get params

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I try to use the params from URL and send them to scheduled script as parameters

This is suitelet on execute

```
try {

            var recordId = context.request.parameters.assemb;
            var form = serverWidget.createForm({
                title: 'Import Inventory Detalis for ID  ' + recordId
            });

      
            var x = recordId;

            if (context.request.method == 'GET') {} else {

                log.debug('x', x)


//calling to scheduled script...
              }



        } catch (e) {
            log.error('onRequest', e)
        }
```

You can see in else statement I log 'x' and there I am getting null.
why the IF statement is blocking my value of recorded?
Note that I am getting the 'recordId' in the first line and can print it on form title. but after IF I cant.

Answer (score 0):

See the code sample below that addresses the different ways to get parameters and pass parameters along while calling a scheduled script.

```
function onRequest(context) {
  if (context.request.method == 'GET'){
    var req = context.request;
    log.audit('Req rcvd', req);
    
    //function to get parameters from url using for loop and split
    function getParameterFromURL(param) {
      var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
      var vars = query.split("&");
      for (var i = 0; i < vars.length; i++) {
        var pair = vars[i].split("=");
        if (pair[0] == param) {
          return decodeURIComponent(pair[1]);
        }
      }
      return (false);
    }

    //OR use regular expression to get parameters from url
    function getParameterFromURL(param) {
      if (param = (new RegExp('[?&]' + encodeURIComponent(param) + '=([^&]*)')).exec(location.search))
        return decodeURIComponent(param[1]);
    }

    //get a specific parameter from Request
    var fieldName = context.request.parameters.custparam_fieldName;

    //get all parameters from request
    var params = JSON.stringify(context.request.parameters);

    //trigger scheduled script to run
    var ScheduledScriptTask = task.create({
      taskType: task.TaskType.SCHEDULED_SCRIPT,
      params: {
        'custscript_fieldName': fieldName //this fieldId exists on the script record as a parameter
      }
    });
    ScheduledScriptTask.scriptId = 111;
    ScheduledScriptTask.deploymentId = 'customdeploy1';
    var scriptTaskId = ScheduledScriptTask.submit();

    //write response
    context.response.write('<h1>Scheduled Script Scheduled</h1>'+'\nReference task id: '+scriptTaskId);

  } else {
    return true;
  }
}
```

If you wanted to create a form for user input before calling the scheduled script, move the contents of "if request method is get" to the else section.  And in the "if request method is get" section add the creation of the form, gathering of data, and a submit button.

Comment: i tried with the functions but its always says that 'location' or 'window' is undefiend

Comment: My guess is "window" is no longer defined when moving from the Suitelet to the custom function.  You could try unwrapping/dismantling the function and putting the desired content within the Suitelet function.  Worse case, please reference https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/49534/ and https://netsuite.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/71494.  Between those two Suite Answers there should be a solution for you.